# Custom sort array in php with first characters

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have values in my array in this format:

```
01001:Bekir
04007:Jean
06934:Marie
06934:Kevin
06934:Bernard
01495:Silvain
01001:Joli
```

...

where "04007:Jean" is one value

I would like to sort my array just for the 6 first characters. For instance, with the 06934, it would give me :

```
06934:Kevin
06934:Bernard
01495:Silvain
```

and not

```
06934:Bernard    
06934:Kevin
01495:Silvain
```

Is it possible ?

Thanks

Comment: In the future, I'd recommend you to take a look at multidimensional arrays from the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is `usort` type of sorting. Using `usort` you can define your own comparison function to be used, for example

```
function first_6_chars_compare( $a, $b ){
    return strcmp( substring( $a, 0, 6 ), substring( $b, 0, 6 ) );
}

$my_array = array(); //
...
usort( $my_array, "first_6_chars_compare" );
```